# Запрос для нескольких таблиц с общей колонкой

Tags: mysql

Есть 2 таблицы, для простоты 2 колонки:

```
 CREATE TABLE users(
    `uid`    bigint NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY
  , `name`   varchar(25)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

 CREATE TABLE blog_users(
    `uid`    bigint NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY
  , `gid`    bigint
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

При этом `users.uid` соответствует `blog_users.uid`, т.е. любая строка из первой таблицы соответствует только одной строке из другой таблицы, и наоборот. В принципе можно было сделать одну общую таблицу, но она будет громоздкой, удобнее её делить на несколько.

Для того, чтобы выбрать из таблицы `blog_users gid` при каком-то условии на `users.name` можно использовать JOIN, но это, как я понимаю лишний цикл.

Как сделать так, чтобы запросы к нескольким таблицам выполнялись наиболее быстро, будто это одна таблица?

Comment: Никак. И вообще структура очень странная, хотя бы потому, что автоинкремент в обоих таблицах. Т.е. я сначала добавил что то в 1ю таблицу не указав id, потом во вторую - не указав id и есть вероятность что обоим записям будет выдан один id, хотя они разные сущности. И "громоздкость" не показатель для столь неординарного решения

Comment: ну т.е. такая архитектура имеет право на жизнь если blog_users это часный случай, "расширение" users. Но тогда uid в нем должен быть явно не автоинкремент и должен быть `foreing`. Ну и запросы просто с join, никаких путей для ускорения работы 2х таблиц в mysql не предусмотрено. как будут работать - так и будут. и причем тут какие то "циклы" совершенно непонятно

Comment: ну при регистрации, скажем, будет добавляться и туда и туда, так что с соответствием проблем не должно быть. Ну а почему такая структура? Вот есть сайт, на нем блог и форум, на форуме свои группы, в блоге свои и т.п. Не делать же одну общую таблицу, по мне так гораздо удобнее работать с двумя таблицами отдельно.

Comment: Ну тогда какие могут быть вопросы к увеличению скорости выборки. Тем более с энжином MyISAM который почти как dbf. данные все равно в разных файлах и как их по диску разбросает предсказать невозможно.

Comment: И кстати если _большинство_ запросов используют только одну таблицу и _некоторые_ обе таблицы - то такое разбиение вполне может увеличить скорость выборки само по себе, просто за счет более короткой записи и соответственно большего кол-ва записей в блоке читаемом с диска. А вообще я бы предложил просто нагрузить в таблицы тестовых данных и поэксперименировать со скоростью что бы выбрать правильную архитектуру. И если например только имя используется часто при доступе к blog, его же можно и скопировать. Это нарушает НФ, но иногда ради скорости такие решения принимаются

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прямой ответ на ваш вопрос - сделать в *MySQL* скорость работы с двумя таблицами аналогичной скорости работы с одной таблице невозможно.

Но по моему вы экономите на спичках, совершенно не заботясь о вагонах бревен. Зачем вам ID типа `bigint`. На земле сейчас проживает 6 миллиардов человек, обычный тип `int` позволяет хранить 2 миллиарда положительных значений. Т.е. треть населения земли сможет пользоваться вашей системой и вам будет хватать этой размерности поля под ID пользователей. А 4 лишних байта в id, это рост длины записи в 2х таблицах, плюс еще страницы индексов. Чем больше места занято на диске - тем медленнее выборка. Кроме того вы используете engine=MyISAM который не отличается компактными записями и плюс к этому очень ненадежен.

Давайте рассмотрим ваш предполагаемый запрос к этим таблицам:

```
select U.uid, U.name, B.gid
  from users U join blog_users B on B.uid=U.uid
 where U.name='Вася'
```

Если таблицы созданы именно так, как вы описали то MySQL на этот запрос сделает следующее: Прочитает с диска *всю* таблицу `users`, найдет в ней 'Васю', возьмет его `uid` по нему полезет в уникальный индекс, построенный автоматически, на `primary key` `blog_users` практически моментально по этому индексу найдет единственную запись во второй таблице, получит из индекса ее адрес на диске и выберет именно ее из области данных. Т.е. 99% времени он потратит на поднятие с диска первой таблицы и поиск там нужных данных и 1% собственно на склейку таблиц. Если вы часто выбираете записи по полю 'Имя' вам надо построить индекс по этому полю:

```
create index users_name on users(name)
```

Или объявите индекс прямо при создании таблицы. В случае наличия индекса MySQL сможет по четко заданному имени мгновенно найти нужные записи в таблице users, после чего по `uid` так же быстро найдет запись во второй таблице.

Подробнее про индексы можно почитать в [руководстве по MySQL](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/MySQL_indexes.html). Пользуйтесь ими по назначению, строить индексы на все поля подряд которые редко встречаются в условиях отбора записей не стоит - они занимают дополнительно место на диске и замедляют операции вставки новых записей и операции изменения данных в проиндексированных колонках.

Answer (score 0):

Как одна таблица не выйдет, но для ускорения выборки можете использовать внешние ключи.

```
CREATE TABLE blog_users(
    `uid`    bigint NOT NULL 
  , `gid`    bigint
  , FOREIGN KEY (uid) REFERENCES users(uid)
) ENGINE= **InnoDB**  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Обратите внимание на движок бд.

Comment: А чем внешние ключи ускоряют выборку ? Они служат в первую очередь для обеспечения ссылочной целостности информации и _обычно_ для их обеспечения автоматически строятся индексы, или не строятся автоматически и это отдается на откуп проетировщику БД, в зависимости от СУБД. Для нормальной скорости выборки нужны просто индексы. И primary на колонке достаточно, т.к. он для обеспечения уникальности всегда реализуется в виде индекса

Comment: >>А чем внешние ключи ускоряют выборку
Проведите тест, даже порядок условий в выборке из нескольких таблиц играет роль...) чем именно внешний ключ ускоряет не скажу, не читал исходника, но на тестах замечал прирост скорости выборки, но замедление вставки)

Comment: Конечно замечали, именно потому, что MySQL при innodb сам строит индексы на фореджены, которые и служат для увеличения скорости. Но вот оракл например сам индекс на таблице с которой идет ссылка строить не будет и откажется делать фореджен если в таблице куда он ссылается уникальный индекс не будет построен до этого отдельно. И если надо ускорить выборку по какому то критерию достаточно просто построить индекс. А primary key который автор вопроса указал в обоих таблицах и есть тот самый уникальный индекс, который как раз обеспечит ему максимально возможную скорость выборки по uid

Comment: Раз вы ставили такие эксперименты, значит заботитесь о производительности, а в таком случае надо знать внутреннюю организацию используемой СУБД и исходники для этого изучать не обязательно. Есть описания в официальной документации http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-storage-engine.html